Do Azure Data Tables `UpdateMerge` and `UpsertMerge` have the same behavior?
I'm in the process of converting a code base from Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table => Azure.Data.Tables in light of the deprecation of the former, and for the most part I've found there to be representative methods in the new api for everything I used in the previous version with the one exception: the Merge operation on the TableBatchOperation class.
Per the docs for the new api, the equivalent should be TableTransactionType.UpdateMerge which, if you wanted to batch out in a way similar to the original TableBatchOperation.Merge,  you'd just create a collection TableTransactionActions specifying TableTransactionType.UpdateMerge as the action type, along with your entity, that collection then being passed to yourClientTable.SubmitTransactionAsync
e.g.
List<TableTransactionAction> myBatch = new List<TableTransactionAction>();
myBatch.AddRange(someListOfEntities.Select(e => new TableTransactionAction(TableTransactionActionType.UpdateMerge, e)));
return myTableClient.SubmitTransactionAsync(myBatch);

What I am noticing though is that whereas the docs indicate that this should perform an update on only existing entities, it is behaving more like the UpsertMerge is indicated, in that if the entity does not exist, it will create it.
This is contrary to the behavior of the Cosmos SDK table api where attempting to Merge with a non-existent entity would throw an error. Has anyone else had this experience of Azure Data Tables api UpdateMerge and UpsertMerge behaving identically, (in spite of indications that they should not)?
from the Azure Data Tables doc:

cosmos doc for merge
azure data tables doc for update entity w/modes

fyi - Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I came here looking for an answer to the same problem i don't seem to understand why behaviour is different from what the docs say.

It seems that you need to add { ETag = Azure.ETag.All } when you crate an instance of TableEntity.
For example:
TableEntity tableEntity = new TableEntity("partitionKey", "rowKey") { ETag = Azure.ETag.All };
You can see the explanation here.
